# Problems with SphinxSearch in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, sphinx, mediawiki-extensions

I got:

- Ubuntu 14
- MediaWiki 1.24.2
- SphinxSearch 0.9.0

SphinxSearch installed as descripted here: [Extension:SphinxSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SphinxSearch)

When I build my Index with
`sudo indexer --all --rotate` i got no errors.

When I do `search "Test"` Sphinx seems to work.

When I enable the Extension in the LocalSettings.php with

```
$wgSearchType = 'SphinxMWSearch';require_once
"$IP/extensions/SphinxSearch/SphinxSearch.php";
```

the search doesn´t find anythin!

What can I do to check the communication between the wiki and the search engine?

Comment: did you start the `searchd` daemon?

Comment: yes, the searchd runs.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the [troubleshooting page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SphinxSearch/Troubleshooting) stoped the daemon with `sudo searchd stop`and started the daemon with

```
sudo searchd --console --pidfile
```

Then the console tells me that the client has the version 1.30 and the server is at 1.25

To get the right version of the client I did the following [descriped here](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=13145)

- do a `sudo indexer --all --rotate`to get the revision. For me its the r3135
- enter this revision into the url https://sphinxsearch.googlecode.com/svn-history/[revision]/trunk/api/sphinxapi.php
- save this file to /extensions/SphinxSearch/sphinxapi.php

Now it works!